# Can I use a HDTV for a digital photo board presentation?

Tags: digital, display, presentation

I need to show 80 photos on a single presentation. The way it used to be done is 80 4x6 photos were printed out and placed into a large frame. This year I would like to do it digitally with a Sharp Aquas 70" 1080p LED Television.
I have two questions:

1)  Would the detail of that many pictures look good on a 1080p TV? These would be pictures with text.

If it would

2)  Is there software that I could easily use to set up a graph style template with drag and drop capabilities?

Answer (score 3):

A 1080p TV has a resolution of 1920x1080 pixels -- that's just two megapixels. If you place photos 10 across and 8 tall, the resolution of each photo should then be 192 x 135 px. Quite small! Too small to include text on, for sure. With so few pixels, there really isn't much ability to show detail, either.

That said, an easy solution on the Mac is to use the "Mosaic" screen saver. You can specify a grid and it'll just cycle through your photos.

Comment: Absolutely: a slideshow is the answer.  You could even add a soundtrack.